# MIDINetworkConnection causing crashing errors

Tags: ios, xcode, midi, coremidi

I am experiencing frequent crashing that I believe is related to this method of checking the number of MIDINetwork Sessions.

```
- (NSString*) describeConnections {
    NSMutableArray* connections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1000];
    for (MIDINetworkConnection* connection in [[MIDINetworkSession defaultSession] connections]) {
        [connections addObject:[[connection host] name]];
    }

    if ([connections count] > 0) {
        return [connections componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
    }
    else
        return @"(Not connected)";
}
```

When the app crashes it stops on the line

```
for (MIDINetworkConnection* connection in [[MIDINetworkSession defaultSession] connections])
```

The error I am getting is

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_1386_GPFLT)
```

In the debugger it shows

```
_impl   _MIDINetworkConnectionImpl *    NULL
```

I have tried to prevent the crashing by checking if MIDINetworkSession is NULL before looping through the connections but that hasn't worked. Occasionally when xcode crashes it will stop at

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Can anyone offer a guess as to what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that connections contain NULL, in some case the system dealloc the connections.But in the set, it cannot use the NULL to be elements, so you should check the connections or use the try catch to get the exception.

Comment: I am still experiencing the app crashing even when checking that connections is not null.